# ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 10061] Connect call failed ('127.0.0.1', 6379) WebSocket DISCONNECT /ws/chat/lobby/ [127.0.0.1:56602]

Tags: django, django-channels

Here, I need to connect another channel using web sockets in django channels. I can't connect to the another channel, it showing error like this.

**consumers.py**

```
import json
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer

class ChatConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        self.room_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_name']
        self.room_group_name = 'chat_%s' % self.room_name

        # Join room group
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

        self.accept()

    def disconnect(self, close_code):
        # Leave room group
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_discard)(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

    # Receive message from WebSocket
    def receive(self, text_data):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message = text_data_json['message']

        # Send message to room group
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)(
            self.room_group_name,
            {
                'type': 'chat_message',
                'message': message
            }
        )

    # Receive message from room group
    def chat_message(self, event):
        message = event['message']

        # Send message to WebSocket
        self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': message
        }))
```

**routing.py***(In django project)*

```
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
import chat.routing

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    
    'websocket': AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            chat.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    ),
})
```

**routing.py***(In chat app)*

```
from django.urls import re_path

from .consumers import ChatConsumer

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'ws/chat/(?P<room_name>\w+)/$',ChatConsumer),
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'chat/index.html')

def room(request, room_name):
    return render(request, 'chat/room.html', {
    'room_name': room_name
    })
```

**urls.py***(In chat App)*

```
 
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from  .views import index,room

app_name = 'chat'
urlpatterns = [
   
     path('', index, name='index'),
     path('<str:room_name>/', room, name='room'),
]
```

**urls.py***(In main project folder)*

```
 
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from chat.views import index

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
     path('chat/',include('chat.urls',namespace = 'chat')),
]
```

**settings.py**

```
 

from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '_94me+sc-lcgo-eo1zrf%!t!q8$rk2b)%e-58u^h2d#v8gzk#j'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'channels',
    'chat'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'justchat.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'justchat.wsgi.application'
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'justchat.routing.application'
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            "hosts": [('127.0.0.1', 6379)],
        },
    },
}

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': str(BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Answer (score 18):

You forgot to run `redis` server.

In official tutorial it is done via `docker` image. At first, you need to install `docker`. After that run `redis` image at 6379 port:

```sh
docker run -p 6379:6379 -d redis:5
```

**Update:**

If you are using Windows, some troubles may arise. `django-channels` comes packaged with `redis` and `in-memory` channel layers. Generally, in development you don't have to use `redis`, just redefine channel layers backend option:

`settings.py`

```py
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "channels.layers.InMemoryChannelLayer"
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure, you can do it on windows, this article may help you: https://koukia.ca/installing-redis-on-windows-using-docker-containers-7737d2ebc25e

Comment: But i can tell you how to perform this without redis and docker

Comment: Yes Please, help me

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using Docker. The Redis can be set up like this. Using Debian Linux distribution, apt package manager and systemctl.

```
sudo apt-get install redis
```

Check if it works

```
sudo systemctl status redis
```

Console output

```
● redis-server.service - Advanced key-value store
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/redis-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2021-12-29 09:59:45 EST; 6min ago
     Docs: http://redis.io/documentation,
           man:redis-server(1)
 Main PID: 10411 (redis-server)
    Tasks: 4 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 7.1M
   CGroup: /system.slice/redis-server.service
           └─10411 /usr/bin/redis-server 127.0.0.1:6379

Dec 29 09:59:45 debian systemd[1]: Starting Advanced key-value store...
Dec 29 09:59:45 debian systemd[1]: redis-server.service: Can't open PID file /run/redis/redis-se
Dec 29 09:59:45 debian systemd[1]: Started Advanced key-value store.
```

Comment: Did the user indicate they were using a linux distribution that use apt and systemctl? Either way, you should probably specify that this is just one of many ways to install and run redis, and it may not be applicable at all to this question.

Comment: A search query of my error led to this question. Added a answer to someone who has a similar problem.
I agree with you. I will add an additional description. Thank you.